# Json XmlDictionaryReader unable to read values which include white spaces

Tags: c#, json

Im trying to read a json file with a `XmlDictionaryReader` created with `JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonReader`. It works well, as long as the values (strings) do not contain white spaces. Otherwise however, I get a weird `XmlException` telling me that names must not contain white spaces.

The exception is thrown when accessing the `XElement.Value` property, what is really weird though is that the property value is accessible and shows the correct value in the debugger.

What is going on here, is this a bug in the JSON XmlDictionaryReader?

JSON:

```
{
    "Names": {
        "Test": { "de": "Hallo space" }
    }
}
```

C#:

```
// using System;
// using System.Collections.Generic;
// using System.IO;
// using System.Runtime.Serialization;
// using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
// using System.Xml;
// using System.Xml.Linq;
// using System.Linq;

using (var inputStream = File.Open(jsonFile, FileMode.Open))
{
    var doc = XDocument.Load(JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonReader(inputStream, Encoding.UTF8, XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max, null));
    foreach (var classNode in doc.Root.Elements())
    {
        foreach (var element in classNode.Elements())
        {
            var defaultValue = element.Name;
            foreach (var desc in element.Descendants())
            {
                if (!desc.HasElements)
                {
                    defaultValue = desc.Value; // throws exception
                    break;
                }
            }
            //var defaultValue = element.Descendants().FirstOrDefault(x => !x.HasElements)?.Value ?? element.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exception do you get?

Comment: `XmlException`: Names cannot contain the ' ' (0x20) char (rough translation)

Comment: Yes, I copied your code, got the exception.

Comment: As the exception says: `The ' ' character, hexadecimal value 0x20, cannot be included in a name.` space cannot be included.

Comment: But the white space is not included in the name, but in the value, which should be fine. And if you set a breakpoint on the line which throws the exception, you will see that you can access and see the correct value in the debugger just fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is not in the reader, but how you store the values. This:

```
    var defaultValue = element.Name;
```

Can be rewritten as

```
    XName defaultValue = element.Name;
```

Later on you are thus trying to an implicit cast. The explicit cast is:

```
defaultValue = (XName)"Hallo space";
```

..which yields the exception.
So the solution is simply...

```
    var defaultValue = element.Name.ToString();
```

Comment: You, Sir, are a life saver :-)